# Where to define persistence.xml in plugin project?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I am trying to do a plugin project which is having eclipselink bundle,and trying to add persistence.xml parallel to MANIFEST.MF file but I am getting this exception.Please provide your suggestions.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your persistence.xml it must be missing the provider name under below mentioned tag.
e.g.
If hibernate

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

If OpenJPA

```
<provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
```

For EclipseLink(Your case)

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error even after adding provider.

Comment: Can you show your project structure which holds the persistence.xml

Comment: Make sure your supportive jars like persistence.jar - eclipselink.jar are in the classpath

Comment: I converted eclipselink.jar,javax.persistence.jar and mysql-connector.jar into bundle and I am using this bundle as a plugin in my project